# What to show on the SonarQube Default dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, sonarqube-web

I would like to show something across all projects in the Default dashboard, so everybody can see something make sense. Can someone give me some good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://sonarqube.com/, the top 3 widgets show a View, but below that, is a Measure Filter widget which shows the results of an instance-wide search. There are a number of Measure Filter visualizations available.

[The docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Measures#Measures-SavingSearchQueryasFilter) describe how to create and save the filter, then display it in a widget.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to create these views and widgets?

Comment: See my expansion @JirongHu